# Excel formula: from a cell value, populate cells (column) with value coming from another worksheet

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010, database

From an original cell, I enter a value  then the formula need to populate other cells , , ...
The data are in the same worksheet that the displaying one. They are organized by row (each row represents a client)

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to switch to another sheet and simply select the value you need by clicking on it. You should end up with a formula like this (that calculated the mean of a value from different the current sheet and another sheet called Sheet1.

```
=(J2+'Sheet1'!J32)/2
```